# MemoryError Precedes BrokenPipeError While Training CNN

Tags: python, caching, memory, pytorch

Generally for running `pip` with no cache we use `--no-cache-dir`, like

`pip install pytorch --no-cache-dir`.

I downloaded a *CNN model* I want to use from [github](https://github.com/jangsoopark/AConvNet-pytorch#quick-start-guide-for-training).
The first two lines of execution

```
 python generate_dataset.py --is_train=True --use_phase=True --chip_size=100 --patch_size=94 --use_phase=True --dataset=soc 
 python generate_dataset.py --is_train=False --use_phase=True --chip_size=128 --patch_size=128  --use_phase=True --dataset=soc
```

executed succesfully. But while running

```
python train.py --config_name=config/AConvNet-SOC.json
```

It is giving `MemoryError`. [image]

The publisher of above repository is using 32GB RAM and 11 GB GPU. But I have 8 GB RAM and 8GB GPU.
*Here is what I have done:*

I thought of running it without cache. like,

```
python train.py --config_name=config/AConvNet-SOC.json --no-cache-dir
```

But it is throwing below error

`FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'no-cache-dir' Pass --helpshort or --helpfull to see help on flags.`

I think it is because `no-cache-dir` argument is not defined in it by using `absl.flags`. *Does python supports using no chache directory implementation*

I am able to solve it by decreasing the number of *epochs* and *batch_size*. But I want to run it for full epochs.

Using `zeo_grad()` of `Pytorch` makes the gradients zero for every minibatch, so that GPU won't run out of memory. But it is already used in the code I am running in [_base.py](https://github.com/jangsoopark/AConvNet-pytorch/blob/main/src/model/_base.py). Is there anyway I can leverage more of this.

How to resolve this.

Comment: Does your abc.py code manage command line switches?

Comment: It's important to understand that in `python abc.py --no-cache-dir`, the command line flag must be handled by `abc.py` not `python`. Also, `python` doesn't handle `--no-cache-dir` according to the help page, i.e. `pip` handling a command line flag doesn't imply that `python` handles the same flag. Lastly, I doubt that caching things to disk would cause a `MemoryError` and therefore it's unlikely that not caching things to disk would resolve the error. Please update the question with the full traceback and a [mre], and we can probably help you resolve this.

Comment: @Fred, I think the `python` script takes `command line switches` as inputs to the python script. That is why it has given `FATAL Flags parsing error:`. But it has taken `--config_name=config/AConvNet-SOC.json` as an argument to the variable defined in `train.py`. How to make it take `--no-cache-dir` or some other way we resolve it.

Comment: @MichaelRuth, I have modified the question to _minimum reproducible example_. The same script ran in _Google Colab_ without any extra arguments required. But in my system it is giving `MemoryEroor`. If it is RAM problem, How to resolve it.

Comment: Resolve a RAM problem by adding more RAM, modifying code to reduce memory usage or reducing system and other applications' RAM usage. What is the available memory on your local host and your Google Collab space? Does your code call `torch.save()` anywhere or does train.py use any libraries which call it?

Comment: `torch.save()` is not used in _train.py_. But `torch` and `torchvision` are used while _loading dataset_ and _validation_ functions of _train.py_